# I want to return unique value counts in C# through input text file

Tags: c#, regex, collections

suppose there are lines like:

> England A team  player : Flintoff
>   England A team  player : Flintoff
>   England B team  player : Strauss
>   England A team  player : Strauss
>   India team player A: Sachin Tendulkar
>   India team player B : Sachin Tendulkar
>   India team player A: Javagal Srinath

Now what i want is to search and return for unique value counts like if i want to search for England players unique counts, it should give me 2 as in above example.

Code i have tried, but is not working :

```
string searchKeyword = "England";
string fileName = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\search tab.txt";
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in textLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
    {
        results.Add(line);
    }
}
List<string> users = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"player:\s*(?<playername>.*?)\s+appGUID");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(searchKeyword);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var user = match.Groups["username"].Value;
    if  (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);
}
int numberOfUsers = users.Count;
Console.WriteLine(numberOfUsers);
// keep screen from going away
// when run from VS.NET
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What way does it "not work"?

Comment: Actually when i debug this, my program is not going into Second "foreach" loop.

Comment: @DheerajSharma, debugging should be your first option before posting here.

Comment: What are you doing with the `Regex`, anyway? Why are you applying it to `searchKeyword`?

Comment: then to whom should i apply ?

Comment: The contents of `results`. `searchKeyword` is just "England," so your regex isn't going to match anything off of it.

Comment: slight modification in question ? Now if i want to find out unique player counts from both england A and england B ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested answers? I'm fairly certain that the dictionary-based solutions will cover any variation of what you're trying to do. Still not sure that you need a regex at all, unless you're suggesting the file won't always be one player per line.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to use LINQ:

```
string searchKeyword = "England";
string fileName = @"C:\Users\renan.stigliani\Desktop\search tab.txt";
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

int numberOfUsers = textLines
                        .Where(x => x.Contains(searchKeyword))
                        .Distinct()
                        .Count();

Console.WriteLine(numberOfUsers);

// keep screen from going away
// when run from VS.NET
Console.ReadLine();
```

As noted by @DominicKexel I swept the foreach

Comment: this will print distinct lines not players. that's why i used regular expressions.

Comment: Well, if you want to use Linq, then why keep the `foreach`-loop and not use a simple `Where`?

Comment: @DheerajSharma That does not make any difference for the input you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound a little simplistic but why don't you just select distinct from your list? 
Example:

```
string searchKeyword = "England";
string fileName = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\search tab.txt";
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in textLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
    {
        results.Add(line);
    }
}
List<string> users = results.Distinct().toList();
```

That will give you unique lines, and you need to split, you can do it easily.
You can know how many unique with the count.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wedded to the Regex approach, you could add the values (e.g. "England player: Foo") to a Dictionary object, making the value the key so duplicates don't get added, and then use the Count method. See also the **ContainsKey** method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to check whether your list already contains the keyword
2. Use dictionary collection.
3. You won't need that regex thing.

---

```
string searchKeyword = "England";
string fileName = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\search tab.txt";
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
Dictionary<string,int> results = new Dictionary<string,int>;
foreach (string line in textLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
    {
        if(results.Keys.Any(searchKeyword))
        {
            results[searchKeyword]++;
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(searchKeyword,1);
        }
        results.Add(line);
    }
}

foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Team:"+item.Key +"\nPlayer Count:"+item.Value);
}
```